# Creating a new column based on the element of next row of existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on cleaning up and re-structured the data frame.

I have the following dataframe:

```
data= pd.DataFrame()
data['ID'] = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
data ['EventSecond'] = [1.5,2,2.5,3,3.8,4,4.8,6,7,8,]
data ['P1'] = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','A','D','E','G']
data ['Code'] = [12,13,16,9,9,0,4,13,14,16]
data ['status'] =['Pass','Pass','Pass','Pass','Pass','Pass','shot','shot','Pass','Pass']
data ['Accuracy']= ['Accurate','Accurate','Accurate','Accurate','Accurate','Not Accurate','Accurate','Accurate','Accurate','Not Accurate']
```

In this data frame, I have ID, Eventsecond etc.
What I want to do is to create a new column **P2** that contains the element of next row of column P1 if the element of column **Accuracy**  is **Accurate**. One thing is if the ID column below is different, I wont take the element from below row and just leave it blank
If the Accuracy is **Not Accurate**, I will leave blank for this row.

**Supplement to the question**

I will only take the rows where the status column has value of **Pass**.

The expected output from this is as follow:

[image]

Can anyone advise on it?
Thanks,

Zep.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I missed out to explain. I will only take the pass in the status columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need `groupby` and `transform`:

```
mask = (data['status'].isin(['Pass','pass']))
data.loc[mask,'P2'] = data[mask].groupby('ID')['P1'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(-1))
data.loc[data['Accuracy']=='Not Accurate','P2'] = np.nan
```

OR using only filters:

```
mask = (data['status'].isin(['Pass','pass']))
data.loc[mask,'P2'] = data.loc[mask,'P1'].shift(-1)
mask2 = data['ID'].ne(data['ID'].shift(-1))|data['status'].eq('shot')|data['Accuracy'].eq('Not Accurate')
data.loc[mask2,'P2'] = ''
```

---

```
print(data)
   ID  EventSecond P1  Code status      Accuracy   P2
0   1          1.5  A    12   Pass      Accurate    B
1   1          2.0  B    13   Pass      Accurate    C
2   1          2.5  C    16   Pass      Accurate    D
3   1          3.0  D     9   Pass      Accurate    E
4   1          3.8  E     9   Pass      Accurate  NaN
5   2          4.0  F     0   Pass  Not Accurate  NaN
6   2          4.8  A     4   shot      Accurate  NaN
7   2          6.0  D    13   shot      Accurate  NaN
8   2          7.0  E    14   pass      Accurate    G
9   2          8.0  G    16   pass  Not Accurate  NaN
```

Instead of NAN if you what blank then use:

```
print(data.fillna(''))

   ID  EventSecond P1  Code status      Accuracy P2
0   1          1.5  A    12   Pass      Accurate  B
1   1          2.0  B    13   Pass      Accurate  C
2   1          2.5  C    16   Pass      Accurate  D
3   1          3.0  D     9   Pass      Accurate  E
4   1          3.8  E     9   Pass      Accurate   
5   2          4.0  F     0   Pass  Not Accurate   
6   2          4.8  A     4   shot      Accurate   
7   2          6.0  D    13   shot      Accurate   
8   2          7.0  E    14   pass      Accurate  G
9   2          8.0  G    16   pass  Not Accurate
```

Answer (score 1):

So first I would create P2 with `shift` from P1 and then create a `mask` with your conditions to change the value in P2 by blank with `loc`, such as:

```
data['P2'] = data['P1'].shift(-1)
mask = ((data.Accuracy == 'Not Accurate') | 
        (data.status =='shot') | 
        (data.ID != data.ID.shift(-1)))
data.loc[mask,'P2'] = ''
print (data)
   ID  EventSecond P1  Code status      Accuracy P2
0   1          1.5  A    12   Pass      Accurate  B
1   1          2.0  B    13   Pass      Accurate  C
2   1          2.5  C    16   Pass      Accurate  D
3   1          3.0  D     9   Pass      Accurate  E
4   1          3.8  E     9   Pass      Accurate   
5   2          4.0  F     0   Pass  Not Accurate   
6   2          4.8  A     4   shot      Accurate   
7   2          6.0  D    13   shot      Accurate   
8   2          7.0  E    14   pass      Accurate  G
9   2          8.0  G    16   pass  Not Accurate
```

EDIT: you can even do it using `numpy.where` like

```
import numpy as np
data['P2'] = np.where(mask, '', data.P1.shift(-1))
```